# Rising Sun RedBud - is 42" away from the fence enough and is it OK if come with slab edging near the trunk?

Tags: trees, planting

I have the below design.
I am about to plant the large tree at the top midle side of of the below plan
As you can see for the lilac tree that is at the corner of the house I did not go around it with the edging (see the second picture)

I would like to do something similar for the Rising Sun Redbud I am about to plant
If I plant the tree on the edging line (which I could interrupt like below) the tree will be around 42" away from the fence. The other option would be to plant the tree closer to the fence to allow the edging to be continuous.

As far as I am seeing these trees don't have a protruding root flare and it could be possible to run the edging very close to the tree trunk. What would you recommend me to do ?

[image]

[image]